# Use `or` or `and` operator on all array's boolean elements and return result

Tags: php

Let's say we have an array:

```
$input = [true, false, false, true, true];
```

What I need is to return a boolean result of `or` or `and` operation on all array's elements, so:

```
and($input); // false
or($input);  // true
```

I am looking for something built-in - not solutions with looping or summing items.

I.e. invalid method:

```
array_sum($input) > 0;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$or  = array_reduce($input, function ($result, $item) { return $result || $item; }, false);
$and = array_reduce($input, function ($result, $item) { return $result && $item; }, true);
```

That's about as "built-in" as it gets.

Comment: While this is correct and "more proper" than my answer, I can't help but think "ew" when I see it XD

Comment: Pfff, array reduction FTW! :P

Comment: Ah, also, you want `false` for an initial value, otherwise `||` will just be true regardless of input. Conversely, use `true` as an initial value for the `&&` operation.

Answer (score 1):

"or" can be fulfilled by `array_filter` without a callback:

```
$result_of_or = array_filter($input);
// result will be truthy if at least one element is true
// otherwise, result is empty array, which is falsy
```

"and" is a little tricker, but could be done like this:

```
$result_of_and = count(array_filter($input)) == count($input);
```

Essentially it removes any falsy values, and then determines if any elements were removed - if none were, then they were all true.